# getting error when trying to use dialog fromvuetify using nuxt

Tags: vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am getting error when trying use the component dialog, it asked to add data-app but when i added it, it show the current error.

```html
<template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
   <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">
      mdi-pencil
   </v-icon>
   <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">
      mdi-delete
   </v-icon>
</template>
```

```js
editItem (item) {
   this.editedIndex = this.orders.indexOf(item)
   this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)`enter code here`
   this.dialog = true
 },
```

Error message:

```
client.js?06a0:102 DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
at VueComponent.initDetach (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js:39715:14)
at Array.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1988:12)
at flushCallbacks (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1914:14)
```

Comment: Hi, please format your code a bit better (+ add some syntax highlight).

Comment: i am trying to use this component from vuetify  ( v-dialog the first one name 'Usage') at this link https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/
firt error is 'Unable to locate target [data-app]'
and when i add data-app at the card it shows the secnd error 
'Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.'